# AntD's Upload keeps showing failed tooltip but it is uploading successfully

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd's Upload component, its task is to just upload the image and then I grab that image and send it to the API to store it. But I keep getting upload failed message tooltip as I am not using any `action` prop that they provide. Even their own website has this problem as I'm trying to upload something and it shows failed message but it has been actually uploaded. [antd's Upload](https://ant.design/components/upload/)

I am using useState to save the file `const [uploadedImage, setUploadedImage] = useState();`

My `fileProps` looks like this:

```
  const fileProps = {
    name: 'file',
    multiple: false,
    onChange(info) {
      if (info.file.status !== 'uploading') {
         let reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = (e) => {
             setData({
              ...data,
              image: new File([e.target.result], info.file.name),
            });
            setIsFileUploaded(true);
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(info.file.originFileObj);
          setUploadedImage(info.file.originFileObj);
      }
    },
  };
```

I then pass it to the Upload Component:

```
<Upload {...fileProps}>
   <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Upload Image</Button>
</Upload>
```

Why does it keep showing Upload error Tooltip even though it is successfully uploading and I can store it? how can I remove this tooltip? I know there is a way to hide the list entirely by using: `showUploadList: false` but I want to show the uploaded file as sometimes during big uploads I don't have any sort of confirmation if the file is uploading or uploaded.

I have also created codesandbox for it: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-bash-g3qkj

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to save the file to the state, and not send it automatically to the server, you must set the property `beforeUpload`.

```
const fileProps = {
  name: "file",
  multiple: false,
  beforeUpload: () => {
    return false;
  },
  onChange(info) {
    if (info.file.status !== "uploading") {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(info.file);
      setUploadedImage(info.file);
    }
  }
};
```